# Generate a fixed number of 1s on random positions

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there a way possible to get the number 1 occurring n Number of times randomly, in a `vector` that should contain only numbers `0` and `1`?

example

1. `vector` size 5, `1` must occur twice randomly in the `vector`

   > [0,1,0,1,0]
2. `vector` size 8, `1` must occur 5 times randomly in the `vector`

   > [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]

etc..

How can it be done in C++?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: we cannot answer this because its not clear, what are the rules about where the repeats occur, for example

Comment: Take a look at [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).  Seems a clear enough question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

void print_v (const std::vector <int>& v)
{
    for (int i : v)
        std::cout << i;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector <int> v;

    v.push_back (1);
    v.push_back (1);
    v.push_back (0);
    v.push_back (0);
    v.push_back (0);
    print_v (v);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g (rd ());    
    std::shuffle (v.begin (), v.end (), g);
    print_v (v);
}
```

Representative output:

```
11000
00011
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DE7MYeIOmxCHYpgU)

(I'll leave constructing the original, unshuffled vector to you).